# Obsession: Vertical Alignment with Chrome on Nexus 6

Tags: css, material-design, vertical-alignment

Link in question: http://goo.gl/w5Vxu7

If you open this link on desktop computer, the vertical aligns are good.

However, on my cellphone, it is not:

[image]

This screenshot is taken from chrome://inspect with my Nexus 6 connected, it is exactly same with the appearance on my phone. You can see the first line is obviously dispositioned.

The small icons are Material Icons, related HTML and CSS are:

```
<div><i class="material-icons">today</i>2012-12-25</div>
<style>
html{font-size:15px;font-family:Microsoft Yahei}
div{font-size:1rem;line-height:1.5}
i.material-icons{line-height:1.4;vertical-align:bottom;font-size:inherit !important}
```

About that `vertical-align:bottom`, it looks a little weird not using `vertical-align:middle`, but I've always had vertical align issues with material icons, especially when accompanied with Chinese characters, which don't have baselines, and I've tried numerous different combinations of `line-height`,`font-size`,`vertical-align`,`font-family` for both the `div` and `i.material-icons` and decided this combination as shown above is the best.

I am quite obsessed with this issue and poured in lots of efforts trying to solve it. Until later I found out this only happens on my Nexus 6. On iPhones and other android phones there is no such problem. Even on my Nexus 6, if I use other browser instead of Chrome, there will be no problem; and even with Chrome, landscape view has no problem, the disposition only happens on portrait view of chrome on Nexus 6. I have only tested so far, but this still could be a potential problem for some mobile devices in some special environment, so it is still not an issue I can simply ignore. And this is where I can use some of this community's knowledge and experience - what could possibly be causing this behavioral discrepancy?

Answer (score 0):

**Vertical align MDI (MaterialDesignIcons)**

The provided link currently returns a white screen, so I can't test your CSS.

The problem with the material-icons shouldn't be solved with a strange combination between height, line-height, padding and so on; explore new attributes. In my case, the following CSS solved the problem.

```
.material-icons{
    display: inline-flex;
    vertical-align: baseline; /* or middle? */
}
```

If the code above doesn't work, try different [display properties](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp).

---

**Worth a try**

My first thought was your use of rem, "older" browsers doesn't support it ([can I use](http://caniuse.com/#search=rem)). It is still strange that it works in landscape, but try to define all measurements in a [safe unit](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp).

**Another *(problem)***

If you want to support older browsers, you shouldn't write the icons in English, IE9 and below won't support it. Use the alternative solution instead (example below).

```
<i class="material-icons">today</i> /* do not use */
<i class="material-icons">&#xE8DF;</i> /* do use */
```

If you click on the [icons](https://www.google.com/design/icons/) and select "<> Icon font", you will be able to copy the html for older browsers.

---

If the information above don't help you, please fix the link (and tell me) and I will check if I can recreate the problem.